# Why was the early question about time zone detection deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, moderators

This long-standing question was recently deleted, with no apparent explanation.

*[Determine a User's Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determine-a-users-timezone)*

[image: Screenshot]

Though some of the answers are outdated, there are a lot of good ones there as well that use modern techniques. I often link to my answer on this post directly, so there are many broken links now. Here is my answer:

[image: Screenshot]

Did something change where we are now deleting questions where the accepted answer is outdated, rather than letting the voting system do its job over time? Or was there something more to it than that?

Maybe it should have just been closed as duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript), or vice versa? But I don't see why it needed to be deleted.

Comment: But closed is different than deleted.  I agree the top/accepted answer is not a great one - but deleting the whole question seems overkill IMHO.

Comment: If it *must* be deleted, then it would be good for the moderator to put a comment in the question explaining why.

Comment: @HansPassant There have been no new flags on that question (or the top answer) since March, and no activity outside of a few votes/favorites since the end of May.

Comment: The question should be closed and locked, not deleted.

Comment: @HansPassant - Near as I can tell, this was the first time this question was deleted. Matt voted to close it as a duplicate of a question that was later merged into this one, which complicates the history a bit, but this appears to be the first time this target question was deleted. I've undeleted it, because I see no reason why it should have been removed.

Comment: I don't see why that question even need to be closed - it asks for one very narrowly defined thing and answer can eventually change from "no, there is none" to "finally W3C decided to add one"... I don't see how it collected 3 too broad/opinion based CVs already...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It's currently either POB or Too Broad; it asks for a standard way to implement something; right now that is read as "is there a normal or preferred way to implement something". If the asker is referring to a specific *published standard*, then we need to know what that standard is. The best we can ascertain is that it's in a web browser, using JavaScript, and maybe server-side. The numerous methods that the answers describe underscore this. There are answers that use JS, that use PHP, that don't mention languages at all, even an answer that recommends VB.NET and C#.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov To be clear, the first scenario in my previous comment merits a POB closure; the second merits a Too Broad closure.

Comment: @TylerH a scenario not considered: why the developer needs to know what time it is for the user?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

## I messed up big time here.

**Big is probably an understatement.** This question should never have been deleted.

The worst part of this mistake is that I have never visited this question or its answers, and neither has this question appeared in the mod flag queue recently. This stumped me for a while and I questioned my sanity while frantically reviewing my browser history and moderation activity.

The cause was an experimental userscript I made to bulk-delete posts from the search results page.

I thought I had this completely under control:

- the userscript was previously trialled several times on a couple of users with verified spam posts
- the search query used was targeted on a specific user (not the one in question) using the filters `user:<uid>` together with the `url:<domain.name>` so it wouldn't return posts by other users

Unfortunately one can never be too careful when *caching* or *regular expressions* are involved, especially when both are thrown in the mix - I should have known better that search results are cached, and regular expressions matching post IDs can go awry if not done correctly.

This post in particular (ID:13) was somehow picked up by a poor regular expression in a search query for a spammy user / domain combination. I have not determined the exact bug in the userscript, but I have since disabled it and [deleted it](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/commit/dd5561a65244d2f8209003634d6ea200226dee7f) from the repository as this must not be allowed to happen ever again.

After extensively reviewing my deletion votes history up to the initial creation of the doomsday userscript, this particular post was the only incident that was incorrectly deleted via this userscript. (I barely used it as there was almost no reason to)

Please accept my apologies for the damage this has caused during the question's downtime, and I swear I will be more careful in future.

In the meantime I will be wearing this paper bag while reviewing the rest of my userscripts...

[image: paperbag]

Comment: Hey, we all make mistakes from time to time.  Don't sweat it.  And thanks for the detailed explanation! :)

Comment: Were any users, CMs, or other moderators aware of this script or involved with it during development, testing, or production use?

Comment: @TylerH I don't usually announce userscripts in development, but I keep the [README of the repo](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md) (with listings and descriptions of all the userscripts I have made or are in development) posted and updated in the private Moderators Team

Comment: @SamuelLiew Gotcha; I think it might be worth making a policy/rule about moderators at least actively informing the moderator team before they implement an automated user script running under such a powerful account.

Comment: "but I have since disabled it and deleted it from the repository as this must not be allowed to happen ever again.

After extensively reviewing my deletion votes history up to the initial creation of the doomsday userscript, this particular post was the only incident that was incorrectly deleted via this userscript" wow, **a single false positive and it is already a doomsday script.** Remember that systems, while not perfect, are in general better than humans, if done correctly. Don't throw the baby with the bath water. Fix the script, make it better.

Comment: Rare to see people confessing and admitting they did a mistake.

Comment: @BillalBegueradj that's part of being a moderator.

Comment: @TheWanderer no, that's just taking responsibility for my own actions

Comment: @SamuelLiew Glad to see that at least on Stack Overflow my elected representative can be held to a high standard of accountability :) Well done and thank you!

Comment: @Braiam It's a single false positive with a _regular expression_. That can spiral out of control quicker than you can count.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 considering the ratio of false/true negatives and that it was available for 7 months, I would say that the regex was very well implemented. If this was a medical study, one patient dead out of thousands would be assigned to random chance. Yes, they would investigate what the reasons of dead were, but the object of research would be allowed to continue.

Comment: @Braiam But computers don't do random. Whatever caused it to do this might one day erase the entire site.

Comment: "bulk-delete ... I thought I had this completely under control" - everybody encounters this at least once. For me it was trying to delete "duplicate" files but then seeing the same file with its alternate filename as duplicate already (when all I wanted was to ensure accessing it thru either name).